# Conditionally add attribute in select option with Aurelia

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am simply trying to create a repeat.for loop which will generate the options for a select element in a form in my application. I wish to add the `selected`
attribute to the last option of my select element but cannot figure out how to manage it. The code for my select looks as follows:

```
<select select class="browser-default" value.bind="maxPlayers">
  <option repeat.for="num of numPlayers" value.bind="num">${num}</option>
</select>
```

and the numPlayers property of my view-model class is just a simple array:

```
numPlayers = [2, 3, 4];
```

So my question is how can I add the selected attribute to only the last option element in my select element? I know that there is a boolean value named $last that indicates whether or not I am on the last element, but I cannot figure out how to properly incorporate that. It seems that I should be able to get it work by adding `selected.bind="$last"` to the option element, but that does not seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `model.bind` on the option elements.  The HTMLOptionElement's value property coerces all values to strings.

Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=9bdbf2518dbd1169d8607f712b09d41b

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <select select class="browser-default" value.bind="maxPlayers">
    <option repeat.for="num of numPlayers" model.bind="num">${num}</option>
  </select>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  numPlayers = [2, 3, 4];
  maxPlayers = 4;
}
```

More info on binding select elements here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.4/doc/article/cheat-sheet/5

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I missed that in the documentation. That does exactly what I need. If you don't mind, would you be able to explain what exactly occurs when I bind to the model attribute?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to compare the `$last` variable with the current `$index` inside the loop like this.

```
<select select class="browser-default" value.bind="maxPlayers">
  <option repeat.for="num of numPlayers" value.bind="num" selected.bind="$index === $last">${num}</option>
</select>
```